# Cyrillic font-face usage with custom wordpress style

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts, font-face, cyrillic

I am using custom wordpress theme and I wanted to change the font. To do that I found the style.css file, and then replaced the current @font-face code with mine, so that I can use the "Stylo" font. This is the code I am using:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'stylo_bold';
src:url("stylo_.eot?") format("eot"),url("stylo_.woff") format("woff"),url("stylo_.ttf") format("truetype"),url("stylo_.svg#Stylo-Bold") format("svg");
font-weight:normal;
font-style:normal;
```

It works fine, except that when I type on cyrillic the font doesn't work and instead the cyrillic text is showed in some default font (Myrad Pro or something). This font has support for the cyrillic letters, so can you point me in the right direction here? I don't understand why it doesn't work? Thank you.

Comment: Are you 100% sure the font support Cyrillic? And does this happen everywhere on the site?

Comment: I have solved it using an online embedded font generator then I just replaced the code and it worked fine. Thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question.

> This font has support for the cyrillic letters...

Many fonts only support english language. A lot of websites will show you a character breakdown or specifically list support for cyrillic alphabet. You must be mistaken or be misinformed in regard to the font in question.

Comment: this doesn't answer anything. If the font has support for cyrilic then why are they not showing with it? Read the question again.

Comment: @ObedMarquezParlapiano Obviously it doesn't.